# C++ How to make a 2D Vector function?

Tags: c++, function, return-value, 2d-vector

I'm trying to create a function in C++ that returns a 2D vector.
The function also has a 2D vector as argument, the idea would be to return a modified version of this 2D vector, with the function.

I won't put my whole code here as is would be totally off the question, but to sum up the function looks like this :

```
using std::vector;

vector<vector<char> > function(vector<vector<char> > grid) {

    int width = static_cast<int>(grid.front().size());
    int height = static_cast<int>(grid.size());

    for(int y=0; y < height; ++y) 
    {
        for(int x=0; x < width; ++x) 
        {
            grid[y][x]= 'H';
        }
    }
    return grid;   
}
```

And I would then do in the **main** :

```
vector<vector<char> > new_grid = function(grid);
```

But it doesn't work in the way I'm using it, so I have a few questions :

1. Should the 2D vector function size be initialized ?
2. Can I change the size of `grid`inside the function and return a bigger 2D vector ?
3. And, it might be a dumb question but, is it actually possible to retrieve a value, an array, a string, in a function without using return, in a void function ?

Thanks for your help !

I can show my whole code if you want but it is quite big and might not be so clear.

Comment: How does it *not work*?

Comment: You need to use the `resize()` function before accessing any vector elements using the `[]` operator.

Comment: if `grid.size() == 0`, call to [grid.front ()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I get, when I compile, the error `control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. 

@πάνταῥεῖ I don't really understand why I should use `resize()` before using the `[ ]`operator ?

Comment: @ReblochonMasqué You get that error for the function you have shown?  To me it does not look like you could get that error with this function.  Please post a [mcve] and include the actual compiler error(s) in the question.

Comment: typo in previous comment.  could should be couldn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver No I don't get this error for the function shown, sorry I should have been more precise, I'm simplifying my code and I will post it as soon as I'm done.

Comment: @NathanOliver I finally found out that by passing the grid by parameter I could simply modify it with a void function. So finally I won't bother you with showing my code and its errors as I found out another way to get the result I expected. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. if you are trying to loop through a vector to set its values then yes it needs to be initialized. a vector starts with 0 elements if you call the default constructor.  To set the size you can call `grid.resize(new_size)`, now all the vectors inside of your grid also have a size of zero so you can loop through grid and resize all of those...
2. Yes you can change the size of it and return a bigger vector, use `.resize` this won't affect your original grid since you are passing in a copy of it and not a reference to it.
3. Yes, you can retrieve a value from a void function, if you create a reference to a variable as a parameter you can modify the value of that variable.  You can read about it here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

If you aren't changing the original grid, it might be a good idea to pass it by const reference so you aren't making so many copies.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful !